# Nodejs - Get client url (dns name) on server side

Tags: node.js, saml, server-side, hapi, callbackurl

I want to get ***client url***, on **server side** to continue (redirect) after authication process :
Inside my script :

```
    ...
    server.register({
        register: require('./libs/hapi-passport-saml'),
        options: {
            callbackUrl: /* I want to put client url her */, 
            issuer: ....,
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
First require url package on top:

```
const url = require('url');
```

Then you can have client url in function:

```
const path = url.parse(req.url).path;
```

Comment: Thank you @kaleem. I have this : 
"ReferenceError: req is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

you can get full url using `req.hostname` and `req.originalUrl` properties.

```
app.get('/foo', (req,res)=>{
   const clientUrl = req.hostname + req.originalUrl;
   console.log(clientUrl);// yourdomainname.com/foo?s=4  full url string
})
```

in the Hapi framework, you can use `server.app.url=request.info.hostname+request.path` and now you are able to use `server.app.url` everywhere you want

Comment: Thank you. How can I add it into "server.register" ?

Comment: you can save it in the app.locals object, for example: `app.locals.url = req.hostname + req.originalUrl ` and you can use it everywhere.
Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application. Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: @kaay in the Hapi framework, you can use `server.app=request.info.hostname+request.path`

Comment: Hello again, I try to do it, but :), on 
```server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
    console.log(request.info.hostname); // ==> I have the hostname ;)
    ....
})
...
    server.register({
        register: require('./libs/hapi-passport-saml'),
        options: {
            callbackUrl: /* how can do it here */, 
            issuer: ....,
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: @kaay I mentioned above ,  assign it (`request.info.hostname+request.path`) to `server.app.url `   and use it ( `callbackUrl: server.app.url`  ) everywhere you want

Comment: OK I do this : 
`
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {   console.log("## server OnRequest : " + request.headers.host); /* => Get the URL : OK */

   server.app.url = request.headers.host;   ... });
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) { console.log("## server OnRequest : " + request.headers.host); /* => Get the URL : OK */

   server.app.url = request.headers.host;   ... });
server.register({ register: require('./libs/hapi-passport-saml'), options: { callbackUrl: /* # 'server.app.url' => undefined # */,
   ...  }
});
`